# How to display in one line that have many behavior in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Our prof gave us an activity about creating a linked list with another class that has attributes or behavior of last name, first name, age, course, etc.

So my question is if I set a cumulative setter with the following given attributes. if I add it to the linked list will the linked list itself will create one list only with the given attributes? and thus if I search it in the list will the linked list need those attributes to be able to search it?

Here's my code for the class with attributes/behavior. I minimized it only with a little attributes so that it is better to correct it:

```
class Student2 {
    public String lastName;
    public String firstName;

    public Student2() {
    }

    public void setlastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setInfo() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your LastName here:");
        setlastName(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your FirstName here:");
        setFirstName(in.nextLine());

    }
}
```

Here's the code of the main method in which the class with attributes will be called. The menu method will ask the user if he/she wants to add a student or search a student on the list :

```
public class Project {
    public static LinkedList<Student2> list = new LinkedList<Student2>();
    public static Student2 info = new Student2();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        menu();
    }

    public static void insert() {
        info.setInfo();
        list.add(info);
        System.out.println("Student  added!");
    }

    public static void search() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the LastName:");
        String lastname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the FirstName:");
        String firstname = in.nextLine();

        boolean found = false;

        for (Student2 student2 : list) {

            if (lastname.equals(student2.lastName) && firstname.equals(student2.firstName)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found) {
            System.out.println(lastname + " found ");

        } else {
            System.out.println(lastname + " not found ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are confused about `LinkedList<Student2>` and think the `Student2` changes something in the list, it doesn't. Before Java 5 (when generics came) the `LinkedList` worked with elements of type `Object`. As every class, your `Student2` too, is of type `Object`, you can put everything into such a `LinkedList`. Nowadays, with generics, the class restricts itself to elements of one, yet unknown, class. For example the class `E` (a placeholder). Later on, when you create the `LinkedList`, you tell it to use `Student2`. It will then only allow `Student2` to be inserted, that's all.

Comment: so meaning the one that I need to use is the name of my LinkedList with the parameter of Student2 (the other class) ? if I am right ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm unsure what you are trying to do. Doesn't your `search` method work? On first glance it looks correct. What exactly confuses you?

Comment: what I'm doing is I have a class Student with a setters and getters of a behavior.  So the Student class will need to initialize it in the main  class to create a LinkedList and can add the Students behaviors to its list. for example, Student has a last name and first name then the program itself will ask the user what will he/she input in the last name and first name after he completed it then it will add it in the LinkedList. then I want to search the one that inputted in the list. and displayed it.

Comment: Yeah, but your code works, doesn't it? You create some students, fill in their values using the setters, then you add them to some kind of `LinkedList` holding all students and afterwards you iterate all saved students and compare their data with the entered one until you found a match. So where exactly is the problem or confusion?

Comment: so if the user's will input in the last name is rose then in the first name is croms then I need to search it then if it's equal then it will be displayed else not found i.  It is easy if there's no other class that will be called so that I can be declared it as A String in the LinkedList parameter but it is a must that there is another class that consists of attributes.

Comment: The thing is after I input a more than one list it overwrites its old data/behavior.

Comment: More than one list? You only have one list and it is supposed to hold multiple students. However the problem is that you only have one student and you keep on changing its data and re-adding it to the list multiple times (everytime you call `insert`). This obviously affects the previously entered students as all your students are effectively just **one** object. You need to create **new students** every time. Your `insert` method should be like `Student2 student = new Student(); student.setInfo(); list.add(student);` and not re-add the same student again and again.

Comment: Ah, I see. so meaning I don't need to declared it as a global variable so that it does not affect the data of the previous one if I want to create a new object?

Comment: Absolutely. Currently your `insert` method changes the data of your student `info` and then re-adds it to the list. `List` allow duplicates, so you end up having a list with the **one** student added multiple times. Every time you change the students data, obviously all entries in the list are affected since they all point to the **same student**. The solution is to create new student objects instead of re-using `info`.

Comment: Thanks man!. You're a lifesaver :). I guess I have a long long way to go. If you may Can I be your friend? :)

Answer (score 0):

No linkedlist will be generic and independent of any behavior. As list doesn't have any information about what object it is going to hold (that is the whole purpose of abstraction). Today, it is student; tomorrow it could be car or burger.

Comment: Ah, I see. So in other words, if I want to search it I just need a local variable to store the data that I want to search and then compare it(equals) to the list?

Comment: No, you are missing the point here. Point here is, you have notion of node which stores your data and pointer (local variable) to next or previous node. Although, while implementing it in any language (java); what you are saying is correct. stick to the basics :-]

Comment: Sorry man, I don't have any experience yet in this kind of situation. On how to search in the list that you've been inputted with many behaviors but I understand that the LinkedList itself is just a container of what data you want to add to the list. Maybe I have a long long way to go.

Comment: what do mean by different behaviors? does it mean different kind of objects in same linked list? if yes, technically possible but not something you should practice. It can give you nightmares. in this case, just iterate over list and perform  (java) equals comparison till you find your desired object.

Comment: I mean different kind , for example in class Student  you need Last name, Firstname(String), age(int), GeneralAverage(double), these class need to initialize in LinkedList and the user is the one that will set the behavior or attributes of the class Student, then if the user wants to search the one that he/she adds then it should be able to search it. I can say that this is already a nightmare for us because we don't have any experience yet in this.

Comment: and it should be displayed in a one line only with the given attributes that the user set/inputted.

Comment: And I have a question, if you may,  If I want to search the one that he/she inputted in the List, for example, the user set a Lastname, First name, then Age and add it to the list. Does that mean if I want to search it I need to have the same one line only with the user that inputted? because a list is just  stored it in a one line only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't get the *base* differences between the classes you are using.

First of all, classes are a *model* that somehow represent the "real" things you want to work with.

Coming from there: a *list* is nothing but a *generic* container of elements. Like a suitcase. You can put many different things into that suitcase, and it doesn't matter (to the suitcase), if you put one shoe into it, or two gloves. It is just a container. And to the contrary: the specifics of the elements in that container should not matter at all to the container.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm a newly programmer student at our school. gaining some knowledge so that I can be a better programmer soon. So in short my code is wrong?

Comment: That is not at all what I am saying. You asked about behavior and lists. I told you that the list is about being a container.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that the list is just a container of what you want to add. 
 but I want to know on how to call or search the one that have many behavior, since I don't have any experience about that kind of problem. The one that I have only experience in using linkedlist is this kind of LinkedList<String> (variablename) = new LinkedList<String>();

Comment: In short, I just want to know on how will I'll be able to search the one that I add in the list with many attributes coming from the other Class,